# Is there a command similar to Matlab's "close all" in R? (How to close all graphics devices?)

Tags: r, matlab, plot

In Matlab, I can use `close all` at the beginning of a script to close the plots to avoid piling up the figures.

Is there a similar command in R?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`graphics.off()` should work. It is implemented by calling `dev.off()` as many times as necessary.

Comment: `rgl` plots use a special device; the equivalent commmand for those is `rgl.close()`.