# How to close rgl X11 windows?

Tags: r, animation, window, rgl

I want to create a 3D animation with `rgl` package. My code is like this:

```
for (frame in 1:100) {
    open3d()
    ... # run some commands here for plotting, like points3d() or spheres3d()
     # Now, save the frame to a png file
    rgl.snapshot(paste0("Frame",sprintf("%04d",frame),".png"))     
}
```

It works fine and creates an snapshot in PNG file for each frame. But after that, there would be 100 open X11 windows. The other problem is that I guess with opening many windows the running time would be too high.

I tried using `rgl.close()` and `clear3d()`, none of them worked fine (they made the output png files to be black).

Is there anyway?

Comment: have you tried `movie3d()` ... ?

Comment: Finally I got it working by replacing `open3d()` with `clear3d()`.

Comment: might as well post that as a solution ...

Answer (score 4):

I realized this is an old question, but this is the simple solution I came up with to close all `rgl windows`.

```
while (rgl.cur() > 0) { rgl.close() }
```

Comment: Also, mentioned as a comment to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449066/command-to-close-plots-in-r

Answer (score 1):

**# rgl.close()** ... works fine and is self explanatory

```
3D visualization device system

Description
3D real-time rendering system.
Usage
# Low level rgl.* interface
rgl.open(useNULL = rgl.useNULL())     # open new device
rgl.close()    # close current device
```